# Create all possible combination from a list without any package

Tags: python

suppose I have a list in python that is

```
['hello', 'yo', 'great', 'this', 'cool', 'fam']
```

how do I get all the possible 2 combinations that I can have from this list in tuples; output example:

```
[ ('hello','hello'),('hello','yo'),('hello', 'great'),...,('yo','hello'),('yo', 'yo') .... ]
```

and so on

no packages allowed

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations, more specific to the class `itertools.permutations(iterable[, r])`

As soon as you have already a tuple and you just need the combinations of 2 elements you can edit the code like

```
n = len(my_tuple)
indices = range(n)
cycles = range(n, n-2, -1)
yield tuple(my_tuple[i] for i in indices[:2])
while n:
    for i in reversed(range(2)):
        cycles[i] -= 1
        if cycles[i] == 0:
            indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
            cycles[i] = n - i
        else:
            j = cycles[i]
            indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
            yield tuple(my_tuple[i] for i in indices[:2])
            break
    else:
        return
```

where `my_tuple` is the input tuple

Answer (score 0):

Well, the desired output is simply the result of the Cartesian product (pairs and order matter), so either you can try this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists) or by using list comprehension:

```
[(entry1, entry2) for entry1 in myList for entry2 in myList]
```

with myList is your input list.

Answer (score 0):

Take the cartesian product between your list and itself:

```
l1 = [hello,yo,great,this,cool,fam]
l2 = [hello,yo,great,this,cool,fam]
l1_x_l2 = [(i1, i2) for i1 in l1 for i2 in l2]
```

or more simply just do

```
l = [hello,yo,great,this,cool,fam]
l_x_l = [(i1, i2) for i1 in l for i2 in l]
```